# Cost to download data from an Azure blob

Tags: http, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a MVC 5 internet application that is hosted on Azure. In this application, the user can upload files to Azure Blob containers. Once a blob has been created, anyone can access the HTTP address for this blob.

My question is this: Is the Azure service free for anonymous users to download data from a blob via HTTP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, **No it is not free for anonymous users to download data from a blob via HTTP**. You, as account owner would pay for 2 things:

1. **Transaction**: Each `GET` request is chargeable. So assuming you have one blob which is downloaded via a single GET request and there are 1000 downloads, you will pay for 1000 storage transactions.
2. **Data Egress**: Every time data flows out of an Azure region, you pay for the number of bytes transferred out. Assuming your blob size is 1KB and there are 1000 downloads for that blob, you will pay 1000 KB data egress.

You may find this blog post useful for understanding storage charges: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx.